DPE with Multiple Currency Writeback User
I have implemented the Advanced Account Forecast and used the Data Processing Engine to calculate transactions. However, I encountered an issue with multiple currencies in the accounts. After running the DPE, I received the following error:
"This run of the Data Processing Engine definition couldn't process the data. The personal currencies for the integration user and writeback user must match. Enter matching personal currency values and try again."
How can I resolve this issue?


You should open a case with Salesforce.
